# How to select if DateRange 1 within DateRange 2 Crystal or SQL?

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

In `Crystal` I'm trying to select a person (and further put them into a count but I have that part handled) based on if they were in housing within a specified date range.

So basically `Bob` lived in an unit from `1/1/2020` (movein) to `5/30/2021` (moveout) and I am trying to find all tenants that lived at the facility from say `1/1/2021` (startdate) to `3/1/2022` (enddate). If a tenant was still living there their `moveout` would be `NULL`.

I have tried this as a range evaluation, date range parameter, a SQL case Statement, various formulas and it just isn't pulling the numbers correctly. Below is my current attempt. I included a SQL tag as there may be an easier way to do this with a Case When statement.

**The Attempt:**

```
Formula 
if ({View_Tenants.movein} <= {?Start Date} and
   {@MoveoutNull} >= {?Start Date})
or
  ({View_Tenants.movein} <= {?End Date} and
   {@MoveoutNull} >= {?End Date})
or
  ({View_Tenants.movein} >= {?Start Date} and
   {@MoveoutNull} <= {?Start Date})
then 1 else 0

Select Statement

RangeAnalysis = 1

MoveoutNull:
if isnull({View_Tenants.moveout}) then currentdate
```

(I also tried this as a way in the future date).

Comment: Hello! Could you adjust your title? The title doesn't let me know much about your issue. Would be great if you do this by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) this post.

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with `SQL`

Comment: I take it this formula is being used in a Formula Field to indicate if each tenant lived in the building during the date range or not.  Do you really need the tenants who did not live there during the date range included in the report?  If no, you could use a formula in Select Expect to only select the tenants who did live in the building during the date range.  Then you don't need the `RangeAnalysis` variable, which will simplify the logic needed in the formula, while also improving performance of the report since it will be parsing/selecting a smaller dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down the logic in plain English:

```
MoveoutNull: if isnull({View_Tenants.moveout}) then currentdate
```

So `MoveoutNull` means the move out date or Today's Date.

```
1 if ({View_Tenants.movein} <= {?Start Date} and {@MoveoutNull} >= {?Start Date}) or
2 ({View_Tenants.movein} <= {?End Date} and {@MoveoutNull} >= {?End Date}) or 
3 ({View_Tenants.movein} >= {?Start Date} and {@MoveoutNull} <= {?Start Date}) 
4 then 1 else 0
```

1. The move in date is less than or equal to the start date and the move out date or today is greater than or equal to the start date. *checks out*
2. The move in date is less than or equal to the end date and the move out date or today is greater than or equal to the end date. *checks out*
3. The move in date is greater than or equal to the start date and the move out date or today is less than or equal to the start date. *This case does not seem logically possible as we are checking if someone moved in after a certain date and then also moved out before that same date.*

I think you just need to change `{@MoveoutNull} <= {?Start Date})` to `{@MoveoutNull} <= {?End Date})` in line 3.